# Panda dataframe: draw bar plot by year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating some new plots, and I'd like to see my data based on the year.
I have data like this given below:

```
  creation_time   physical_device_type
---------------   --------------------
7/25/2018 14:53   email
7/26/2018 14:53   printer
7/26/2017 14:53   email 
7/24/2017 14:53   printer
7/23/2017 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email
```

I'd like to see various graphs as year on the x axis.

```
temp_col = ['creation_time', 'physical_device_type']
df = pd.DataFrame(self.data_frame, columns=temp_col)
grouped = df.groupby(['creation_time','physical_device_type'])
df['creation_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_time'])
df.index = df['creation_time']
grouped_df = df.groupby([(df.index.year),'physical_device_type'])

grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped_df.size().reset_index(name='count'))
grouped_df.plot('creation_time', kind='bar')
```

The above code gives me plot with the two bars for 2018.

I want to see in 2018 how many email and prints.
Each year I want to see the details.

Comment: I see you've asked 15 questions but still not marked any answers as the accepted answer. If you receive a useful answer to a question, just click the checkmark below the answer score to accept it as the answer to your question. Among other things, that makes it easier for everyone to see if they should take a closer look at your question and maybe even provide a solution.

Comment: I have done that thanks for informing me

Comment: No problem. And as you probably noticed, you gain reputation points for doing so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pivot_table`:

```
(df.pivot_table(
    index=df.creation_time.dt.year,
    columns='physical_device_type',
    aggfunc='size').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap='dark2', width=0.2)
)
```

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a loop to filter your dataframe on the year. Make sure that your column `creation_time` is in the format pandas datetime for that.

Creation of the dataframe:

```
temp = u"""creation_time   physical_device_type
7/25/2018 14:53   email
7/26/2018 14:53   printer
7/26/2017 14:53   email 
7/24/2017 14:53   printer
7/23/2017 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email
7/22/2019 14:53   email"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),delim_whitespace = True).reset_index()
df['creation_time'] = df['index'] + ' ' + df['creation_time']
df.drop('index',1,inplace = True)
df.creation_time = pd.to_datetime(df.creation_time)
```

Extract the year and plot:

```
df['year'] = df.creation_time.dt.year
for year in df.year.unique():
    df.loc[df.year == year].groupby('physical_device_type').agg(len).plot(kind = 'bar')
    plt.title(year)
```

But it is not a very pythonic way to do it, and there is probably more elegant and efficient.

Comment: its giving me two separate plot windows one for 2018 and another for 2017. I'm looking for single plot with all the years in the x axis and email,print count for each year in the y axis